# How does Icabod know John's mother?

Tags: plot-explanation, patriot

In S02E04 of Patriot, while John is traveling through the subway, he sits across from his mother and Icabod. Seeing the condition John is in, they both come over to John and hug him.

How does Icabod know John's mother?

Answer (score 1):

They had just met.

Earlier in S02 (E01, I think?), John called his mother from the airport in Paris, and she flew to Luxembourg to meet them, as John and Tom expected to be back in Luxembourg by the time she arrived. When she did arrive, everyone was still in Paris, so Tom sent Ichabod to pick up Bernice because he thought Ichabod would freak Bernice out.

So in the scene you're asking about, they had only known each other for as long as it takes to travel from Luxembourg to Paris. Note that when Ichabod joins in the hug, Bernice gives him a strange look, but then seems to shrug it off and go with it.